# Tesseract OCR extraction

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract

I am building an OCR model where I have performed object detection on the images. I am calling the detection function to detect bounding boxes. I am cropping the images basis bounding boxes. The challenge I am facing is the cropped images are too small for tesseract for data extraction and it is impacting the accuracy quality.

```
# Crop Image
cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min)

# write jpg with pillow
img_pil = Image.fromarray(cropped_image.numpy())

score = bscores[idx] * 100

file_name = OUTPUT_PATH + "somefilename"
          
img_pil = ImageOps.grayscale(img_pil)
img_pil.save(file_name, quality=95, subsampling=0)
```

I am running super resolution algorithm over the cropped images to improve the image quality before passing to tesseract, however still not able to achieve good accuracy.

```
# Create an SR object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Define model path
model_path = os.path.join(base_path, model + ".pb")

# Extract model name, get the text between '/' and '_'
model_name = model_path.split('\\')[-1].split('_')[0].lower()

# Extract model scale
model_scale = int(model_path.split('\\')[-1].split('_')[1].split('.')[0][1])

# Read the desired model
sr.readModel(model_path)

sr.setModel(model_name, model_scale)
```

How to fix these cropped images issue so that data extraction is more accurate.

Comment: superres "hallucinates" information. prepare to get bogus results from your OCR if you run it on "superres" output.

Comment: I am not able to understand your comment, could you please give some more pointers

Comment: do you mean that ocr on super resolution image will give bad accuracy??

Comment: let's try this differently. what does superres do? what are the limits of superres? what is "information"? what can superres make out of a picture that is unreadable even to you as a human? -- superres has no clue what "text" is. OCR should be doing by itself what you are trying to do with superres. -- please research these things a little more on a theoretical level.

Comment: superres magnifies the image, the limit is that over magnification lead to losing important information from the image.

Comment: not _loss_ as such. you simply *do not **gain*** information. you get more pixels but not more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried OCRing and then cropping, rather than the reverse? It may take longer but it is likely going to be more accurate.

I have a lot of experience using ocrmypdf with PDFPlumber and Regex to parse PDF documents into spreadsheets and this is the process I generally follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pdfplumber
import re

#OCR PDF
os.system('ocrmypdf --force-ocr --deskew path/to/file.pdf path/to/file.pdf')

text = ''

with pdfplumber.open('path/to/file.pdf'):
     for i in range(0, len(pages)):
          page = pdf.pages[i]
          text = page.extract_text()
          pdf_text = pdf_text + '\n' + text

ids = re.findall('id: (.*)', text)

y = pdf_text.split('\n')
ds =  []
for i,j in enumerate(ids):
    d = {}
    try:
        id1 = ids[i]
        idx1 = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(y) if id1 in s][0]
        try:
            id2 = ids[i+1]
            idx2 = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(y) if id2 in s][0]
            z = y[idx1:idx2]
            except:
                z = y[idx1:]
            except:
                pass
    chunk =  ''
    #may need to add if/else or try/except
    d['value'] = re.findall('Model name: (.*)', chunk)[0]
    #rinse and repeat
    ds.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)
```

Not sure how helpful that will be, but it may give you some inspiration.